# Arguments in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to programming and had this random question crossed my mind while learning for loop:

```
import pandas as pd 
name = ['Amy','Luke','Anderson']
occupation = ['Data Scientist','Lawyer','Teacher']
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'occupation':occupation})

for a, b in df.iterrows():
   print(b['name'] + ' is a ' + b['occupation'])
```

In the print line, `b` is used in `b['name']` and `b['occupation']` but not `a`. Why is it okay that `a` is not mentioned?

Comment: What does the `iterrows` docs say?

Comment: Don’t use `.iterrows()`, learn to read the documentation and do research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print `a` you will notice that `a` is just line number, just like using `enumerate` wrapping `for` loop

Comment: `print(a)` returned `2`. May I ask why?

Comment: the last value of `a` is 2 (all values while looping are `[0, 1, 2]`)

Answer (score 2):

Because if you print `a` you will print just line number while part of each row, is a part that is not needed to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Because `a`, while part of each row, is a part that is not needed to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

a is the row index, 0,1,2. IT's not required for your loop.

Answer (score 1):

a is just the index, but if you don't need it simply replace with _.

Answer (score 1):

Because `a` and `b` are index and row.